# How to edit PayPal referral code (BN code) in magento?

Tags: magento, paypal

How can I change PayPal referral code (BN code)in maganeto Paypal standard module.  Which file i need to edit ? I don't see a place to edit it on admin side.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look in to the following file

```
app/code/core/Project/Paypal/Model/Config.php
```

make following structure

```
app/code/local/Project/Paypal/Model/Config.php
```

Or override `Config.php` in custom module.

Please reply if it works for you.